# Entity Framework complex type's columns naming convention

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Using complex types the default column naming convention uses underscore. That means having type defined that way:

```
[ColmplexType]
public class Contact
{
    string Email {get;set;}
    string Post {get;set;}
}

public EntityN
{
    //...
    public Contact Contact {get;set;}
}
```

we will get columns named such way

```
Contact_Email nvarchar(max)
Contact_Post nvarchar(max)
```

We of course could configure each column name separately using ColumnAttribute or Context.Properties mapping, but do we have a possibility to create naming convention and therefore configure all names in once for currnet type?

For some of complex types I would prefer do not mention property name ("Contact") at all for others connect  name and attribute using CammelCase, and never would use undersore.

**Discussion:**

That works (create configuration info for specific table)

```
    public class CustomComplexTypeAttributeConvention : ComplexTypeAttributeConvention
    {
        public override void Apply(ConventionTypeConfiguration configuration, ComplexTypeAttribute attribute)
        {
            Properties().Where(pi => pi.DeclaringType == typeof(Contact))
               .Configure(p => p.HasColumnName(p.ClrPropertyInfo.Name)
            );
            base.Apply(configuration, attribute);
        }
    }
```

and OnModelCreating

```
modelBuilder.Conventions.AddBefore<ComplexTypeAttributeConvention>(new CustomComplexTypeAttributeConvention());
```

It works, but I'm not sure is it a right way to coding:
1) does the "AddBefore" works as expected (I do not want to delete default behaviour, just want to override default behaviour for one case)?
2) where is the best option to put "custom code" to Apply method or to the constructor.

The breakpoint and disassembling of ComplexTypeAttributeConvention brings an idea that  we do not override "default" naming convention but utilize "loop" through "all attributes of all types".

This looks like most solid solution, but it is still a "hack" (it does not override default "underscore" convention, but emulates presents of "ColumnAttribute"):

```
    public class BriefNameForComplexTypeConvention<T> : Convention
    {
        public BriefNameForComplexTypeConvention()
        {
            Properties().Where(pi => pi.DeclaringType == typeof(T))
               .Configure(p => p.HasColumnName(p.ClrPropertyInfo.Name)
            );
        }
    }
    // ...
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Add(new BriefNameForComplexTypeConvention<Contact>());
```

Comment: I think this is the wrong attribute to modify - looking at the EF source code, this is just marking types as ComplexTypes (along with ComplexTypeDiscoveryConvention).  What we should be looking for is the convention that constructs the ColumnName for ComplexTypes

Comment: This seems like a bad idea.  This will break, for example, EntityFramework.MappingAPI, which derives a property name from a column named like "Contact_Email", converting it to a property search like "Contact.Email".  If Contact or Email were different, it would not be able to find the properties on the object and the mapping would fail.  This is also a problem with properties or columns that contain underscores.  As a matter of convention, it's probably best to not screw with the column names of complex types.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've never done this before but it's worth trying the `ComplexTypeAttributeConvention`, you can remove the default one and add the custom one to `DbModelBuilder.Conventions`:

```
public class CustomComplexTypeAttributeConvention : ComplexTypeAttributeConvention {
    public CustomComplexTypeAttributeConvention(){
       Properties().Configure(p => p.HasColumnName(p.ClrPropertyInfo.Name));
    }
}

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder){
   modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<ComplexTypeAttributeConvention>();
   modelBuilder.Conventions.Add(new CustomComplexTypeAttributeConvention());
   //...
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It works. But I have some open questions left, could you explain for me them?

Comment: Also I have reflected the original ComplexTypeAttributeConvention class... And didn't find default "underscore" behaviour there? May be you know where it is hidden?

Comment: @RomanPokrovskij the documentation about ComplexTypeAttributeConvention is very limited. I think removing the default and adding the custom one as in my code is fine. Because the custom one ***inherits*** from the default one without overriding any thing. It just configures the properties via `Properties()` (which is a member of the `Convention`). I don't think we can do much in the `Apply` method (we may still have to use `Properties()`). I'm not sure why but I've seen some others writing code for custom `Convention` do like that.

Comment: In fact I've not even tried this code myself when posting this answer. Googling around also did not find anything.

Comment: I have put a breakpoint to your code and have found that constructor is called for every attribute for every class (not only complex type) in the model. I guess you do not expect it. So I think we should add little safety and scope management to real solution.

Comment: I have tested - it works from Apply also. And it seems it works because we call Configure for every "attribute" in the system. I mean this solution is not about "override of convention", but about easy looping through every attribute in the model... It seems we could put the same code to EVERY XyzAttributeConvention and it would work

Comment: it's so surprising that it is executed for all Types not just ComlexTypes. If so we in fact can use a custom Convention (which inherits directly from `Convention`). It's some kind of unexpected behavior I was not aware of. Currently I'm not sure how to filter for just ComplexTypes from the `Properties()` (but if filtering for a specific type, we can do like what you did).

Comment: @RomanPokrovskij how is your ComplexType mapped? I mean you use DataAnnotation or use Fluent API? Well looking at the convention name, looks like it's used for DataAnnotation configuration.

Comment: Yes inheritance from just `Convention` works also. And there are no Apply method! No dilemma what to chose, but new question why "higher" conventions needs Apply.