# Entity Framework: Naming complex types without underscore

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

With this model

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public TypeA PropertyOfTypeA { get; set; }
}

[ComplexType]
public class TypeA
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

I end up with the columns `Id`, `PropertyOfTypeA_Name`, and `PropertyOfTypeA_Description`.

The problem is that i need to remove the underscore to follow a naming convention. These are the column names i want: `Id`, `PropertyOfTypeAName`,`PropertyOfTypeADescription`.

I am able to name the columns manually like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MyClass>().Property(x => x.PropertyOfTypeA.Name ).HasColumnName("PropertyOfTypeAName");
```

Is there a way to do this without having to name these columns manually. TypeA will be used in several classes and in properties with different name.

I've tried going of the answer for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33238109/entity-framework-complex-types-columns-naming-convention), but I am missing the first part of the column name (`PropertyOfTypeA`)

Comment: Have a look at this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.mapping.columnattribute(v=vs.110).aspx